# Calling a global variable from a method (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, global-variables, glade

I was wondering if it is possible to declare a global variable inside of a method so it can be called and used inside of another UI method. The code I have written below is supposed to take the theresholds file that the user chooses and then is supposed to print it out when the run button is clicked.

```
class Handler:

    def on_filechooserbutton1_file_set(self, widget):
        self.Thresholds = widget.get_filename()
        with self.Thresholds as a:
            global Thresholds
            Thresholds = pd.read_table(a, sep=',')

    def on_RUN_clicked(self, widget):
        print Thresholds

    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)


builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("DataAPP.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

window = builder.get_object("MainWindow")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()

print Thresholds
```

The thresholds variable contains a dataframe and has previously been defined, but whenever I try to call the threshold variable outside of its method I get an error stating:

```
NameError: global name 'Thresholds' is not defined
```

Any suggenestions on how to go about doing this properly?

Comment: A global `Thresholds` won't exist until `on_filechooserbutton1_file_set` is run at least once.

Comment: If you think it needs to be global, reconsider your design.  From the way you describe the problem, it sounds like you can simply do self.Thresholds

Comment: I have done this, but I will be filtering that file and will be using that information for other parts of the UI I am building.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the global variable first:

```
Thresholds = None

class Handler:
    ...
```

Comment: I have tried this and when I go to print my thresholds dataframe I get None as an output

Comment: @mdicrist which `print` are you talking about?  the one in main script or the one in handler?

Comment: I need the main script to print out in the handler. No worries though I've found a way to make it work. The global statement worked. I had to change my `with self.Thresholds as a:` line to `with open (self.Thresholds) as a:`. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my syntax to open up the file was wrong. To print the Thresholds file both when the button is clicked and in the main script, the following code works:

```
class Handler:

    def on_filechooserbutton1_file_set(self, widget):
        self.Thresholds = widget.get_filename()
        with open (self.Thresholds) as a:
            global Thresholds
            Thresholds = pd.read_table(a, sep=',')

    def on_RUN_clicked(self, widget):
        print Thresholds

    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)


builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("DataAPP.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

window = builder.get_object("MainWindow")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()

print Thresholds
```